# Is there a function that produces the decimals of π?

Tags: functions, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Is there any function Ψ defined for all n ∈ ℕ such that Ψ(n) yields the nth decimal of π? Can such a function exist? How about for any irrational number?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: You mean some restriction from all possible functions because otherwise you have already given the function. Do you want there to be a formula?

Comment: Not only is there a function $\Psi$, the function is computable. There is also a function for every other real number that gives the digits of the decimal representation of the number, but not all of those functions are computable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula may be useful, though it is in hexadecimal instead of decimal

Comment: And not only _can_ such a function exist, **you have just defined it**.

Comment: [See also here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411418).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is such a function, and as comments indicated, you gave enough definition to uniquely chracterize the function, so there it is.

The function is even computable (which is not required for a function to exist). One way to compute it: simply compute $\pi$ to sufficiently many digits, then extract the one you need.

But I guess that's not what you meant. You probably wanted a simple formula or algorithm to compute one digit without computing all the preceding ones.  The Wikipedia article on Pi has a [section on spigot algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Spigot_algorithms) dealing with this. According to that, the [BBP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) and its derivatives can do so in hexadecimal, which can easily be adopted to other power-of-two number systems, but “no digit extraction algorithm has yet been found that rapidly produces decimal digits”. But a footnote there clarifies that Plouffe did find a decimal function, it's just slower than computing all the digits first. There is more detail in [the section on digit extraction methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Digit_extraction_methods) in the article on the computation of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you can do so for any $x \in [0, 1)$. Let 
\begin{align*}
\psi (1) & = \lfloor 10 x \rfloor, \\
\psi(k + 1) & = \left\lfloor 10^{k + 1} x - \sum_{j = 1}^{k} 10^{k + 1 - j} \psi(j) \right\rfloor,
\end{align*}
where $\lfloor t \rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\leq t$. This is just the standard algorithm for finding the decimal expansion of $x$.

Comment: Or just $$\psi(k)=\left\lfloor10^kx\right\rfloor-10\left\lfloor10^{k-1}x\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: @bof Good catch.